# debug c# application

Tags: c#, sign

I want to debug a c# application, it's a big application and I can't build it all by myself. I can only build a portion(a DLL) for that. The application installed in my machine is built by others. But after I rebuild the DLL by myself and replace the DLL currently in my machine, the new DLL can't be loaded. I guess the reason is in the old DLL it has the key of the author so that we can't replace it with my customized one. If it's the case, is there any hackable method to replace the DLL with my own one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to bypass strong name verification for a [given assembly](http://blogs.msdn.com/mapo/archive/2007/05/24/skipping-strong-name-validation.aspx) or [globally](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2008/05/14/strong-name-bypass.aspx) but be warned that this could pose a **HUGE** security problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after reading the article I still has some confusion. If I want to disable all the applications' strong name verification in my machine, can I just set the registry value of AllowStrongNameBypass to 1? I can only learn how to disable the bypass, but what i want is to enforce the bypass. Thanks.

Comment: By setting the value in the registry all applications on this machine will bypass strong name verification when loading dependent assemblies. If you want to exclude some applications from doing so you set the `bypassTrustedAppStrongNames` setting in their respective configuration files.